# How to mimic Java's Wildcard types in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have an interface which I defined like this:

```
Public Interface ISomething(Of T)
' methods
End Interface
```

I now did an implementation:

```
Public Class ConcreteThing
Implements ISomething(of SomeClass)
' Implementation
End Class
```

I have multiple such concrete implementations, and want to have a function which returns any of them based on its parameters. In Java, I would do something like this:

```
public ISomething<?> getSomething(ParamType p) {
    if(p.hasFoo()) return new ConcreteThing();
    if(p.hasBar()) return new OtherConcreteThing();
    throw new IllegalStateException("p neither has Foo nor Bar");
}
```

I already searched about this issue and found out that VB.net does not have wildcard types, so I tried:

```
Public Function GetSomething(p as ParamType) as ISomething(Of Object)
    If p.HasFoo Then Return New ConcreteThing()
    If p.HasBar Then Return New OtherConcreteThing()
    Throw New InvalidOperationException("p neither has Foo nor Bar")
End Function
```

This compiles, but I get the warning: `Runtime errors might occurr when converting 'Foo.ConcreteThing' to 'Foo.ISomething(Of Object)'`.

When I try the following, as suggested in a similar question:

```
Public Function GetSomething(Of T)(p as ParamType) as ISomething(Of T)
    If p.HasFoo Then Return New ConcreteThing()
    If p.HasBar Then Return New OtherConcreteThing()
    Throw New InvalidOperationException("p neither has Foo nor Bar")
End Function
```

the warning only changes to `Runtime errors might occurr when converting 'Foo.ConcreteThing' to 'Foo.ISomething(Of T)'`.

So, how do I get this right? Or, if this indeed IS right, how do I have Visual Studio ignore this warning?

Comment: You could return `GetSomething` as `Object`, but this is a graceless solution.

Comment: This would, IMHO, be uglier than all the warnings.

Comment: Ha! That's why I said graceless  ;o) but `Object` is a catch all.

Comment: Is it possible to filter these warnings then? In Java you would have to do an unchecked cast from the `ISomething<?>` to anything, like `(ConcreteSomething)(Object)theSomething`, but there you can put this in a separate method, and annotate it with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated on this issue a little more, discussed it with my colleagues, and I think I found the solution / reason for the warnings.

The warning message is a bit hard to understand and unconcise. What they are trying to say is that, as silly as it sounds, covariance does not work as expected for primitive types, even when using the `Out` keyword!

Consider an excerpt from [this example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx):

```
    ' Covariance.  
    Dim strings As IEnumerable(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    ' An object that is instantiated with a more derived type argument  
    ' is assigned to an object instantiated with a less derived type argument.  
    ' Assignment compatibility is preserved.  
    Dim objects As IEnumerable(Of Object) = strings
```

This works. Now, change the first `IEnumerable` to `IList`:

```
    Dim strings As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim objects As IEnumerable(Of Object) = strings
```

Works, too. OK, we are lucky, let's change the second:

```
    Dim strings As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim objects As IList(Of Object) = strings
```

Boom, `InvalidCastException`. Looking at the signature, this is because the generic parameter in `IEnumerable` is defined as `Of Out T`, and `IList` is only defined `As T`.

Now, let's define our own.

```
Interface ISomething(Of Out T)
    ReadOnly Property Value As T
End Interface

Class IntThing
    Implements ISomething(Of Integer)

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Integer Implements ISomething(Of Integer).Value
        Get
            Return 42
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Now, do this:

```
Dim s1 As ISomething(Of Integer) = new IntThing()
```

Works. Now add this:

```
Dim s2 As ISomething(Of Object) = s1
```

Boom, `InvalidCastException`. Now, the funniest part. Add a second implementation of `ISomething`:

```
Class StringThing
    Implements ISomething(Of String)

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As String Implements ISomething(Of String).Value
        Get
            Return "foo"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And do:

```
Dim s1 As ISomething(Of String) = New StringThing()
Dim s2 As ISomething(Of Object) = s1
```

This, on the other hand, works! So, let's go back to the List example.

```
Dim ints As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()
Dim objects As IEnumerable(Of Object) = ints
```

This will get you an `InvalidCastException`, too.

So, my conclusion is that covariance not only needs the `Out` keyword, it additionally only works with non-primitive types. .net seems to handle wrapper classes differently to the JVM.

So, never ignore this warning when it pops up. When it does, things will go wonky in an absolutely illogical way! That means, for what I want to achieve, going with simple `Object`s instead trying to find an equivalent for `ISomething<?>` is the way to go.
I only use this internally to read a binary file into a more convenient structure to extract the data I pass out via the API in the end, so using `Object` does not make things very much worse here.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, I don't get the warning like you do.  But I do get an `InvalidCastException` if I try to run the code.

To get rid of the error (and hopefully your warning as well), you can make the generic type `T` on `ISomething` covariant.

```
Public Interface ISomething(Of Out T) ' Add the "Out" keyword here to make it covariant
' methods
End Interface
```

Then you should be able to use your `GetSomething` function as you had attempted:

```
Public Function GetSomething(p as ParamType) as ISomething(Of Object)
    If p.HasFoo Then Return New ConcreteThing()
    If p.HasBar Then Return New OtherConcreteThing()
    Throw New InvalidOperationException("p neither has Foo nor Bar")
End Function
```

Relevant documentation: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Covariance**
>
> Enables you to use a more specific type than originally specified.
>
> You can assign an instance of `IEnumerable<Derived>` (`IEnumerable(Of Derived)` in Visual Basic) to a variable of type `IEnumerable<Base>`.

And lower in the **Defining Variant Generic Interfaces and Delegates** section:

> A covariant type parameter is marked with the `out` keyword (`Out` keyword in Visual Basic, `+` for the MSIL Assembler).

Comment: I added the `Out` keyword but the warnings did not go away. I am still using VS2010 and .net 4.0, maybe something changed in the meantime.

Comment: What happens when you actually try to ***run*** the code, both with and without the `Out` keyword?

Comment: With the `Out` keyword, it runs fine, without, I get the `InvalidCastException`. So, you are right, I need the `Out` keyword, but this does not eliminate the warnings.

Comment: Are you sure it's VS giving you the warning and not some VS extension?  What is the warning code? (e.g.: `BCnnnnn`)

Comment: In VS, in the `Error List` window, where you get the list of errors and warnings, next to the error/warning description, you should see a code that usually looks something like this: `BC42104`.

Comment: Another thought: Try fixing the code by adding the `Out` keyword, then close and reopen VS, and then rebuild.  Sometimes, VS can get stuck showing a warning that is no longer relevant.  Restarting VS may fix that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86620/discussion-between-rabejens-and-sstan).